# Web Service Connection Refused

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I'm trying to connect to my web service, the trouble is my connection is getting refused. I am running WAMP on a server that the web service is running on and I am running Apache Tomcat8 on eclipse. Here is the stack trace:

```
Dec 06, 2014 8:08:39 PM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and     javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
faultActor: 
faultNode: 
faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:153)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:120)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at DefaultNamespace.WebserviceSoapBindingStub.echo(WebserviceSoapBindingStub.java:106)
at DefaultNamespace.message.main(message.java:18)

{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:Shadow

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at DefaultNamespace.WebserviceSoapBindingStub.echo(WebserviceSoapBindingStub.java:106)
    at DefaultNamespace.message.main(message.java:18)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    ... 11 more
```

Here is the client as well:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
public class message {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
        String a = in.next();

        WebserviceServiceLocator locator = new WebserviceServiceLocator();
        WebserviceSoapBindingStub stub;
        try {
            stub = (WebserviceSoapBindingStub)locator.getwebservice();
            System.out.println(stub.echo(a));
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

Echo just returns what you put into it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I was working with webservices deployed on glassfish and it was because I previously killed the glassfish process, thus the server stopped running. That's why the conncetion between the client and the webservice couldn't be established. Check if your Tomcat server is still running.